# How to generate .pbtxt file from a .pb file for dnn module in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, dotnetnuke

I have a custom tensorflow model .pb file. I want to import that in OpenCV using the dnn module. dnn module function requires 2 parameters: `.pb` file and `.pbtxt` file? How can I generate `.pbtxt` file from the `.pb` file?

```
cvNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('FrozenMaster.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')
```

How to get this `graph.pbtxt` file?

Comment: Where did you get the .pb file from? If you made it yourself, what version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16879) issue out for creating frozen_inference_graph.pb from a saved_model.pb.

Answer (score 4):

```
import cv2 
cv2.dnn.writeTextGraph('FrozenMaster.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')
```

Moreover the following link of opencv github might as well be useful https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API